# Using name and 3d models of real product

Tags: legal

I'm making tycoon game where you manage your shop. I'm not 3d modeler and purchase most of assets. I managed to find all 3d assets required for making game. All are having license to allow use for commercial usage. My question is can I use those model who are clearly modeled after their real world product in my game? Even though license for each of them permits me.
I know,I can't use their real name like for example I will change nintendo switch to ginmendo ditch or apple to mapple. I'm even planning to slightly modify each asset in 3d modeling software. will that work? Can I use them in my game ?

Comment: [What do previous questions in the legal tag tell you about this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blegal%5D+name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can legally modify all of these assets to avoid copyright infringement. TV Shows have edited products like apple by turning them into pears or other fruits. Video games have changed other products around to look like something in the real world, but not *exactly* close enough to get sued. Make sure to change both the logo and the company name itself.

**Word of advice**: Check the licensing rights for modification. Unlicensed modification of assets can lead to C&D orders.